# RegSvr32.exe fails to launch

Tags: winapi, dll, com, regsvr32

I'm trying to register a 64-bit, COM-based DLL into the registry through the 64-bit `regsvr32.exe`. However, after clicking on "Run as Administrator", `regsvr32.exe` shows the following message box:

[image: Error message]

The message box disappears after clicking OK or Close, and nothing else happens.

What could have been possibly gone wrong?

Comment: You can't run `regsvr32.exe` directly like you are.  It is a command-line program, you need to run it from inside a command prompt window so that you can then provide it with required input parameters, like the path to your DLL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open up a command prompt in administrator mode and write

```
C:\>regsvr32 {path to where .dll is}
```